# Me aparece undefined method

Tags: ruby

```
require "./contact.rb"

class ContactList
  attr_accessor :contacts

  def initialize()
    @contacts = Array.new()
  end

  def add_username(contacts)
    contacts = Contacts.new(contacts)
    @contacts.push(contacts)
  end

  def remove_username(index)
    @contacts.delete_at(index)
  end

  def remove_all
    @contacts.clear
  end

  def show_all
    if @contacts.length == 0
      puts "No hay contactos en su agenda"
    end
  end
end
```

I was hoping it would allow me to make a hash in which to save, edit, delete names and numbers. Help please

Comment: irb(main):004:0> contact = Contact.new()
=> #<Contact:0x3456600 @contacts={}>
irb(main):005:0> contact.add_username(Name: 003)
NoMethodError: undefined method `add_username' for #<Contact:0x3456600 @contacts={}>
        from (irb):5
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'

Comment: `Contact` and `ContactList` are two different things.